# с# Переопределение метода ToString()

Tags: c#

Я переопределил метод ToString() в базовом и производном классе, однако в объекте производного класса мне нужно вызвать переопределенный метод базового класса ToString(), как это сделать? Однако мне нужен переопределенный метод в производном классе такой какой он есть, я его использую (просто код урезал для читаемости)

```
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {    
             Cruise cruise = new Cruise();
             Console.WriteLine(cruise.base.ToString());//Но так делать нельзя в статическом методе
        }
    } 
    public class Hotel
    {
   
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Свободных мест " + Convert.ToString(sv) + " " + "Занятых мест: "  + Convert.ToString(reserved);
            return s;
        }
    }
    class Sanatory : Hotel
    {
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Кол-во медиков: " + Convert.ToString(medics);
            return s;
        }
    }
    class Cruise : Hotel
    {
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Осталось: " + Convert.ToString(stop) + " остановок";
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что значит "мне нужен"? Нам плохо видны мысли в Вашем мозгу.

Comment: переопределенный метод ToString() в производном классе Cruise я использую в Main`е для вывода информации на консоль.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что Вы получаете сейчас, и что Вы хотите получить? Задаю вопрос последний раз. Если Вы будете продолжать валять дурака, ставлю еще один минус и ухожу.

Comment: ToString() класса Cruise нужен для вывода информации про кол-во остановок, однако в нем не должно содержаться другой информации кроме информации об остановках. Так же я должен выводить общую информацию "Круизного лайнера" переопределенным методом ToString() базового класса(Под общей информацией подразумеваю Кол-во свободных и занятых мест лайнера,). У меня круизный лайнер делает остановки на протяжении круиза, и я должен на каждой остановке выводить общую информацию и информацию об количестве остановок. С каждой остановкой с лайнера съезжает 10 человек.

Comment: Просто добавь в производный класс еще один метод, в котором будет вызываться только `base.ToString ()`

Comment: Была такая идея, у меня она даже реализована, но неужели нельзя больше никак по-другому сделать?

Comment: Вы хотите вызывать один и тот же метод, но чтобы он возвращал разные результаты?

Comment: Да, по заданию мне нужно именно это сделать

Comment: Это дурацкое задание. Не делайте его.

Comment: можно сделать с помощью рефлексии, но самый простой вариант добавить метод, если тебе действительно нужен и базовый метод и метод наследника

Answer (score 0):

```
base.ToString();
```

---

```
class Sanatory : Hotel
{
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s = "Кол-во медиков: " + Convert.ToString(medics) +
          Environment.NewLine + base.ToString();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Через сокрытие производного метода, и приведение типа, вроде, получилось сделать, то что надо

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {    
             Cruise cruise = new Cruise();
             Console.WriteLine(((Hotel)cruise).ToString());
        }
    } 
    public class Hotel
    {
   
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Свободных мест " + Convert.ToString(sv) + " " + "Занятых мест: "  + Convert.ToString(reserved);
            return s;
        }
    }
    class Sanatory : Hotel
    {
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Кол-во медиков: " + Convert.ToString(medics);
            return s;
        }
    }
    class Cruise : Hotel
    {
        
        public new string ToString()
        {
            string s = "Осталось: " + Convert.ToString(stop) + " остановок";
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поверьте, это не то, что надо.